# Form is not using POST

Tags: php, forms

My form doesn't seem to be using POST.

```
<?php foreach($users as $user) : ?>
  <tr>
  <form action "index.php" method "post" name='form1'>
  <td align="center" width="40%" ><?php echo $user['FullName']; ?><input type="hidden" name="FullName" value="<?php echo $user['FullName']; ?>" /></td>
  <td width="30%"><input type="number" name="NumberedEntered"></td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
  </form>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I use the following code in index.php, nothing is returned:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  $NumberedEntered= $_POST['NumberedEntered'];
  $FullName= $_POST['FullName'];
    echo $NumberedEntered;
    echo $FullName;
}
```

If I change the POST to GET, it works.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Should be `method="post"` and `action="index.php"` you are missing the `=`.

Comment: There is also no `input type="int"` and did you mean to put `<?php $_POST['NumberedEntered']; ?>` in `value=""` instead of `name=""`? And you are missing an opening `<tr>`. Do you have the `<table>...</table>`? Your `<form>` element would also be in the wrong place.. so an awfull lot of invalid HTML.

Comment: @putvande That value field is absolutely fine, as he wants to transmit the name along the form. Also the form tags are on the right place, as each row of the table has its own submit button. This might not be the based ui approach but if it fits the needs...

Comment: The `<form>` tag is **not** in the right place as it is outside a `<tr>` tag which makes it invalid.

Comment: I've updated it now. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: @putvande Thanks for teaching me something new! I wasn't aware that this restriction is existant. regarding this it might be way better to use civs instead of a table for this application.

Comment: Just put the `<form>` inside the `<td>` tag is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `=` in `<form>` tag :

```
<form action "index.php" method "post" name='form1'>
```

replace to

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name='form1'>
```

Comment: I cant believe I missed that! Cheers.

Comment: You were quick, posted first for 3 seconds, +1

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a few equal signs in

```
<form action "index.php" method "post" name='form1'>
            ^ here             ^ and here
```

change it to

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name='form1'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing `=` after `method`. Should be:

```
 <form action "index.php" method="post" name='form1'>
```